# Getting [: !=: unary operator expected in a shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I am writing a simple shell script to send me an email in case my server has gone down, but for some reason I'm getting a syntax error, I'm not sure why..

> ./reverse-proxy-test.sh: line 26: [: !=: unary operator expected

```
status="$(curl -Is --connect-timeout 5 --max-time 5 http://192.168.1.11/ | head -1)"
validate=( $status )

if [ ${validate[1]} != "301" ]; then
  mail -s 'curl failed for - Reverse proxy!!' martin@gmail.com <<< 'Curl failed for reverse proxy to (192.168.1.11). Server is down!!'
fi
```

Comment: Looks like `${validate[1]}` might be empty?

Comment: @TomFenech yes it can be empty, in that case the email should be sent... (I don't understand why it's not working) I mean empty is still != "301"

Comment: You need to put quotes around `${validate[1]}`, so it will test `[ "" != "301" ]`

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote your variables!

In case `${validate[1]}` is empty, your test becomes:

```
[ != "301" ] # syntax error
```

Whereas if you added double quotes `"${validate[1]}"`, it would be:

```
[ '' != "301" ] # valid comparison
```

Since you have tagged [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) then you also have the option to use an extended test `[[` instead of `[`, which handles this case better, meaning that the quotes aren't necessary:

```
[[ ${validate[1]} != "301" ]]
```

Although it doesn't do any harm to use quotes here either, and many would recommend that you did.

Comment: Oh, I see.. I didn't know about the quotes. That solved my problem! Thank you!